# Creating a segue programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I have a common `UIViewController` that all my `UIViewsControllers` extend to reuse some common operations.

I want to set up a segue on this "Common" `UIViewController` so that all the other `UIViewControllers` inherit.

I am trying to figure out how do I do that programmatically.

I guess that the question could also be how do I set a `segue` for all my `UIViewControllers` without going into the story board and do them by hand.

Answer (score 170, accepted):

By definition a segue can't really exist independently of a storyboard.  It's even there in the name of the class: `UIStoryboardSegue`.  You don't create segues programmatically - it is the storyboard runtime that creates them for you.  You can normally call `performSegueWithIdentifier:` in your view controller's code, but this relies on having a segue already set up in the storyboard to reference.

What I think you are asking though is how you can create a method in your common view controller (base class) that will transition to a new view controller, and will be inherited by all derived classes.  You could do this by creating a method like this one to your base class view controller:

```
- (IBAction)pushMyNewViewController
{
    MyNewViewController *myNewVC = [[MyNewViewController alloc] init];

    // do any setup you need for myNewVC

    [self presentModalViewController:myNewVC animated:YES];
}
```

and then in your derived class, call that method when the appropriate button is clicked or table row is selected or whatever.

Comment: Thanks. It's a shame we can't do it programmatically. It would really boost up the quality of source code (less duplication is always good). I'll have a go with your suggestion.

Comment: there are situations in which is not possible to create segues from IB, in example: if i want to bind the disclosure button of a mapview annotation i have not any item to drag in IB at design time. Anyway the fact is "we can't" so let's do it manually.

Comment: @jonkroll is it possible to call / perform segue from switch statement i.e. based on what index i have?

Comment: @codejunkie: Yes, you can do that. You would use the `UIViewController` method named `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` for this.

Comment: I’ve been creating and performing segue programmatically (see my answer). Anything wrong with my code, then, if your answer is correct?

Comment: Update for iOS 6+ : `UIView`'s `presentModalViewController:animated:` is deprecated. From the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#presentModalViewController:animated:)- *(Deprecated in iOS 6.0. Use presentViewController:animated:completion: instead.)*

Comment: The swift equivalent to this selected answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24035984/instantiate-and-present-a-viewcontroller-in-swift

Comment: #jonkroll : is it possible to push a UIViewController 'A' (that is not inside framework) from a UIViewController 'B' (B is view controller inside that framework).

Comment: The definition of a segue never excluded an entirely programmatic implementation; that defies logic. Interface Builder is just a quick way to write code; there's nothing at all that it does differently than that. See my answer below...

Answer (score 347):

I thought I would add another possibility. One of the things you can do is you can connect two scenes in a storyboard using a segue that is not attached to an action, and then programmatically trigger the segue inside your view controller. The way you do this, is that you have to drag from the file's owner icon at the bottom of the storyboard scene that is the segueing scene, and right drag to the destination scene. I'll throw in an image to help explain.

[image]

A popup will show for "Manual Segue". I picked Push as the type. Tap on the little square and make sure you're in the attributes inspector. Give it an identifier which you will use to refer to it in code.

[image]

Ok, next I'm going to segue using a programmatic bar button item. In viewDidLoad or somewhere else I'll create a button item on the navigation bar with this code:

```
UIBarButtonItem *buttonizeButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Buttonize"
                                                                    style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                                                                   target:self
                                                                   action:@selector(buttonizeButtonTap:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = @[buttonizeButton];
```

Ok, notice that the selector is buttonizeButtonTap:. So write a void method for that button and within that method you will call the segue like this:

```
-(void)buttonizeButtonTap:(id)sender{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Associate" sender:sender];
    }
```

The sender parameter is required to identify the button when prepareForSegue is called. prepareForSegue is the framework method where you will instantiate your scene and pass it whatever values it will need to do its work. Here's what my method looks like:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Associate"])
    {
        TranslationQuizAssociateVC *translationQuizAssociateVC = [segue destinationViewController];
        translationQuizAssociateVC.nodeID = self.nodeID; //--pass nodeID from ViewNodeViewController
        translationQuizAssociateVC.contentID = self.contentID;
        translationQuizAssociateVC.index = self.index;
        translationQuizAssociateVC.content = self.content;
    }
}
```

I tested it and it works.

Comment: @MichaelRowe how does this eliminate the need for segues? As i see it you still have to drag and drop on Storyboard to the destination controller..

Comment: @MichaelRowe this doesn't eliminate the need for segues. What this does is let you segue between view controllers that are built in code instead of in interface builder.

Comment: @Matt it actually just go me completely rethinking how I setup my app... After a complete rewrite of all the UI I no longer use any segues..

Comment: @cocoanut i am getting the error as "Application tried to present modally an active controller" any help regarding this..

Comment: Manual Segue "Push" is deprecated, use "Show". [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24184003/adaptive-segue-in-storyboard-xcode-6-is-push-deprecated) has more details. @smileBot please update the answer.

Comment: This worked for me, but i had to use "Show" instead of "Push" and i didn't use the last method in this answer and it still worked. Thank you a lot +1!!!!

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the question, which would mean I do not understand the answer … my goal is to change the source of the UIStoryboardSegue, so I can push it from a presented view controller. If I want to do that, the NIB seems to be the right solution

Answer (score 82):

I've been using this code to instantiate my custom segue subclass and run it programmatically. It seems to work. Anything wrong with this? I'm puzzled, reading all the other answers saying it cannot be done.

```
UIViewController *toViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"OtherViewControllerId"];
MyCustomSegue *segue = [[MyCustomSegue alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"" source:self destination:toViewController];
[self prepareForSegue:segue sender:sender];
[segue perform];
```

Comment: It is a custom subclass of `UIStoryboardSegue`.

Comment: Whatever you want. Most likely, the button that was tapped and triggered the segue. The OS doesn't care.

Comment: @MarkAmery A lot of people (including me) avoid using storyboards. They're hard to merge, and there's no compile-time check that the ID I’m passing to `performSegueWithIdentifier:` is really defined in the storyboard. I avoid all problems if I create the segue myself.

Comment: Merci beaucoup Jean-Philippe! I have MANY pages that all require an exit to a Main Menu, using a custom segue animation.
Creating all the links on the storyboard would have been ridiculous. Very useful code, merci.

Comment: I agree with Jean-Philippe. Managing storyboard is a pain in the butt. Of course it's easy to click your way through crating few views and adding a segue here and a segue there, but managing 6 views with 16 segues defined in XML, when you have three developers all fiddling with it is terrible. Anyway, the point is: code gives you control, xml generated by xcode does not.

Comment: I see a crash in [segue perform] in iOS7, not sure if anyone else is experiencing this.

Comment: @fjlksahfob Why would it have to exist? It's been 3 years now and I don't work on that project, but IIRC we didn't use storyboards at all.

Comment: ```UIViewController *toViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"OtherViewControllerId"];```

this line in your answer means the controller has to be instantiated from a storyboard. If you don't have a controller with that ID your app will crash...

Comment: @fjlksahfob Ah, sure, in this case, but nothing prevents me from actually instantiating it programmatically as well.

Comment: Using this, the app crashes and I get the error "A segue must either have a performHandler or it must override -perform".

Comment: @Minimi This means your UIStoryboardSegue subclass must override the perform method or you must use UIStoryboardSegue's alternate constructor that implements the perform block.

Answer (score 44):

Guess this is answered and accepted, but I just would like to add a few more details to it.

What I did to solve a problem where I would present a login-view as first screen and then wanted to segue to the application if login were correct. I created the segue from the login-view controller to the root view controller and gave it an identifier like "myidentifier".

Then after checking all login code if the login were correct I'd call

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"myidentifier" sender: self];
```

My biggest misunderstanding were that I tried to put the segue on a button and kind of interrupt the segue once it were found.

Comment: As I wrote as another comment: I’ve been creating and performing custom segues programmatically (see my answer).

Answer (score 32):

You have to link your code to the `UIStoryboard` that you're using. Make sure you go into **YourViewController** in your `UIStoryboard`, click on the border around it, and then set its `identifier` field to a `NSString` that you call in your code.

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" 
                                                     bundle:nil];
YourViewController *yourViewController = 
 (YourViewController *)
  [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yourViewControllerID"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:yourViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: I get this, but what if the viewController I want to present is embedded in a NavigationController in the storyboard? From what I can find, I can initialize a NavigationController to embed it in but in the storyboard, I already have push segues setup for the view that needs to be presented.

Comment: can you elaborate on this? I think this is the problem I am having, but can't seem t find how/where to do this...

Comment: Even this solution is a correct one, It's about avoiding any segue, but the question is about segue. In this way you can connect or make a transition between two scene WITHOUT segue in the storyboards.

Answer (score 16):

For controllers that are in the storyboard.

jhilgert00 is this what you were looking for?

```
-(IBAction)nav_goHome:(id)sender {
UIViewController *myController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController: myController animated:YES];

}
```

OR...

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loginMainSegue" sender:self];
```

Answer (score 3):

well , you can create and also can subclass the UIStoryBoardSegue . subclassing is mostly used for giving custom transition animation.

you can see video of wwdc 2011 introducing StoryBoard. its available in youtube also.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStoryboardSegue_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIStoryboardSegue

Answer (score 3):

Storyboard Segues are not to be created outside of the storyboard. You will need to wire it up, despite the drawbacks.

[UIStoryboardSegue Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIStoryboardSegue_Class/Reference/Reference.html) clearly states:

> You do not create segue objects directly. Instead, the storyboard
>   runtime creates them when it must perform a segue between two view
>   controllers. You can still initiate a segue programmatically using the
>   performSegueWithIdentifier:sender: method of UIViewController if you
>   want. You might do so to initiate a segue from a source that was added
>   programmatically and therefore not available in Interface Builder.

You can still programmatically tell the storyboard to present a view controller using a segue using `presentModalViewController:` or `pushViewController:animated:` calls, but you'll need a storyboard instance.

You can call `UIStoryboard`s class method to get a named storyboard with bundle nil for the main bundle.

`storyboardWithName:bundle:`

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to add a clarification...

A common misunderstanding, in fact one that I had for some time, is that a storyboard segue is triggered by the `prepareForSegue:sender:` method. It is not. A storyboard segue will perform, regardless of whether you have implemented a `prepareForSegue:sender:` method for that (departing from) view controller.

I learnt this from Paul Hegarty's excellent [iTunesU lectures](https://itunesu.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/LZDirectory.woa/ra/directory/courses/593208016/feed). My apologies but unfortunately cannot remember which lecture.

If you connect a segue between two view controllers in a storyboard, but do not implement a `prepareForSegue:sender:` method, the segue will still segue to the target view controller. It will however segue to that view controller unprepared.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

First of, suppose you have two different views in storyboard, and you want to navigate from one screen to another, so follow this steps:

1). Define all your views with class file and also storyboard id in identity inspector.

2). Make sure you add a navigation controller to the first view. Select it in the Storyboard and then Editor >Embed In > Navigation Controller

3). In your first class, import the "secondClass.h"

```
#import "ViewController.h
#import "secondController.h"
```

4). Add this command in the IBAction that has to perform the segue

```
secondController *next=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"second"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:next animated:YES];
```

5). `@"second"` is secondview controller class, storyboard id.

Comment: `self.storyboard` should be: `UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];`

Comment: @masipcat and the Story board name might depend on how you set up your Xcode project, in mine it was "Main.storyboard" so I used `storyboardWithName:@"Main"`

Comment: @sanket-chauhan if your first controller is not embedded in a Navigation Controller, you can also show the next view using `[self showDetailViewController:next sender:self];` or `[self showViewController:next sender:self];`

Answer (score 1):

I reverse-engineered and made an open source (re)implementation of UIStoryboard's segues: https://github.com/acoomans/Segway

With that library, you can define segues programmatically (without any storyboard).

Hope it may help.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of problems, actually:

First, in that project you uploaded for us, the segue does not bear the "segue1" identifier:

no identifier

You should fill in that identifier if you haven't already.

Second, as you're pushing from table view to table view, you're calling initWithNibName to create a view controller. You really want to use instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code sample for `Creating a segue programmatically`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    ...
    // 1. Define the Segue
    private var commonSegue: UIStoryboardSegue!
    ...
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        ...
        // 2. Initialize the Segue
        self.commonSegue = UIStoryboardSegue(identifier: "CommonSegue", source: ..., destination: ...) {
            self.commonSegue.source.showDetailViewController(self.commonSegue.destination, sender: self)
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // 4. Prepare to perform the Segue
        if self.commonSegue == segue {
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
    func actionFunction() {
        // 3. Perform the Segue
        self.prepare(for: self.commonSegue, sender: self)
        self.commonSegue.perform()
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: You are calling `self.prepare(for: self.commonSegue, sender: self)` from your action method. Then what's the point of comparing `if self.commonSegue == segue {...}` in `prepare(for:sender)` method?

Comment: @nayem: In `prepare(for:sender:)`, you can configure the destination view controller prior to it being displayed. Of course you can also do it in `actionFunction`.

Comment: @nayem: The reason I do this is to try to be consistent with the handling of other segues.