# How to make a global segue?

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, segue

I have a complex storyboard, and I've costumizated the navgation controller to have a fix header with 3 buttons (client demanding). This three buttons pushes 3 different views, no matter where you are on the app.

So what I want is to have a kid of "global segue". Like a segue that no matter if I'm on the VC1 or VC2 or VC3, if I call `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueToMe" sender:self ]` it will go to the correspondent view.

Is there any way of doing that? I want to avoid, to have 7/8 segues directing to each one of that 3 viewControllers.

Comment: Any update on this? I'd love to hear some answer too.

Comment: I not found the answer, so I make all the segues I needed :S

Comment: Look At that Answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674685/creating-a-segue-programmatically