# Creating segue from UIImageView to other viewcontroller programatically

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, storyboard, segue, xcode4.6

I have created few thumbnails of images dynamically and i want to display detail description about that image in other viewcontroller when the respective image is clicked. I am using Storyboard (universal) in Xcode 4.6.

I am new to Xcode can anyone suggest me how to create segue for transitioning to new View Controller when the image is clicked or tapped

Any suggestions or examples will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Edit:

I am not able to get the click on the uiimageview which is subview of the uiscrollview and the images are created dynamically.

Also wanted to know that is there a way by which i can come to know which image is being clicked.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674685/creating-a-segue-programmatically

Comment: @ProFFeSSoR i first :D

Comment: thx @Bimawa will try that solution can you please help me with the edited part in the above question.

Comment: Just post your question in other topic. Maybe someone else helped you.

Comment: thx @Bimawa i got solution to that edit part from my friend