# Invoking push segue programmatically and prepareforsegue method

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uistoryboard, segue

I'm invoking `push segue` programmatically as below

```
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [mainStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"addToCartViewContollerForItem"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController: vc animated:YES];
```

but my problem is I want to send some info with this segue to the destination viewcontroller. But the method `- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender` is not getting fired at all.

this is how the prepareforsegue method

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    NSLog(@"segue from deals screen");
    //addToCartViewContollerForItem
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"addToCartSegue"]){
        NSIndexPath *selectedRow = [[self tableView] indexPathForSelectedRow];

        Item *currentItem = [[Item alloc]init];
        currentItem = [itemList objectAtIndex:[selectedRow row]];

        RESTAddToCartViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        [vc setCurrentItem:currentItem];
    }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: On which action you want the segue to happen, like unbutton action or uitableview cell selection?

Comment: uitableview cell selection. I did it using `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: You can directly use prepareForSegue method without didSelectRow method with the code you written or you can call perform segue from your didSelectRow method, check my answer.

Comment: I think the main confusion is in the first line of the post.  That navigation controller push does not perform a push segue.  self performSegueWithIdentitifer is the way to do that, as @suhit suggests.

Comment: @dahn rightly said, UINavigationController pushViewController does not perform the push segue, best way is performSegueWithIdentitifer and  prepareForSegue: method.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Call `performSegueWithIdentifier`: from your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"addToCartSegue" sender:self];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    NSLog(@"segue from deals screen");
    //addToCartViewContollerForItem
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"addToCartSegue"]){
        NSIndexPath *selectedRow = [[self tableView] indexPathForSelectedRow];

        Item *currentItem = [[Item alloc]init];
        currentItem = [itemList objectAtIndex:[selectedRow row]];

        RESTAddToCartViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        [vc setCurrentItem:currentItem];
    }

}
```

**in Swift 2.3**

```
//MARK: didSelectRowAtIndexPath

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("addToCartSegue", sender: self)
}


// MARK: - Navigation

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    if segue.identifier == "addToCartSegue" {
        let selectedIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
        let currentItem: Item = itemList[selectedIndexPath.row]
        if let viewcontroller = segue.destinationViewController as? RESTAddToCartViewController {
            viewcontroller.currentItem = currentItem
        }
    }
}
```

**Swift 3**

```
//MARK: didSelectRowAtIndexPath

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "addToCartSegue", sender: self)
}

// MARK: - Navigation

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "addToCartSegue" {
        if let selectedIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let currentItem: Item = itemList[selectedIndexPath.row]
            if let viewcontroller = segue.destination as? RESTAddToCartViewController {
                viewcontroller.currentItem = currentItem
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks It worked 

Thos who face similar issue must read this answer too http://stackoverflow.com/a/17012857/2636704

Answer (score 0):

This is the information that you are looking for :

```
 (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showRecipeDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        RecipeDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.recipeName = [recipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
}
```

prepareForSegue will get called along with `[self perform segue]`
 and this is the [tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/storyboards-ios-tutorial-pass-data-between-view-controller-with-segue/) you should definitely look into.

Comment: It's a good answer if he were performing segue properly.  But this code won't get called until he does performSegueWithIdentifier:

Comment: I actually want him to check out the tutorial for the rest, because that's exactly what he is trying to do.