# prepareForSegue is not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, segue

1. I create a `scrollView` using storyboard.
2. I programticaly created 10 myController(which are `UITableViewControllers`) inside the `scrollViewController`, So I can use `panGesture` to switch between tables. and it's working fine.
3. I created a `tableViewController` using storyboard, set myController to be the corresponding view controller.
4. Embedded the `tableViewController` in navigation controller.
5. Control drag from table cell to a new view controller to create a push segue.
6. Setup segue.

when running the app, `prepareForSegue:` is never called.

**Edit:** After noticing this issue, I did the follow thing but with no luck.

I also set the segue identifier in storyboard correctly. and add the following code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueIdentifier" sender:self];
}
```

but when I tap any table cell on screen, program will crash with following error:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver () has no segue with identifier 'segueIdentifier''
*** First throw call stack:

Why is that?

Comment: The error is self-explanatory, isn't it? The segue you're trying to perform does not exist in your storyboard. You probably forgot to name it or there is a typo in the identifier.

Comment: I did add segue identifier by clicking the segue icon and put text in identifier box. is that what you talked about?

Comment: Yes, although I'm pretty sure it has to do with your programmatically created controllers. Segues only work in tandem with storyboards, but you could try creating a manual segue. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674685/creating-a-segue-programmatically/17012857#17012857

Comment: I've checked the identifier again, no problem at all, exactly the same.

Comment: Does it match `segueIdentifier`? The two have to be the same. Also make sure that you hit enter (or return) after typing otherwise it won't set.

Comment: in didSelectRowAtIndexPath: I've added manual segue method. and tried control drag from tableviewcontrol(not from cell) to another viewcontroller. but still the same problem.

Comment: @CaptJak Exactly the same!!!!

Comment: And you still get the same error?

Comment: @CaptJak Yes! same error :( Where's the problem????

Comment: What is `Receiver`? Is that another View Controller? Is that the tableViewControl?

Comment: @CaptJak it's the tableviewcontroller!! reason: 'Receiver (<tableViewController: 0x8a96df0>) has no segue with identifier 'test''

Comment: Just to clarify, you ctrl+click from the view controller (not the view) to the destination VC and named the segue "test". Then you put `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"test" sender:self];` right? Make sure it's the entire VC that you segue from, not just the view.

Comment: @CaptJak Yes, I'm sure I did exactly the same like you said.

Comment: I have no idea unless I see the storyboard as well as the rest of the tableviewcontroller.

Comment: @CaptJak I posted detail information on another question, would you have a look? Thank you so much! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20842833/segue-with-correct-identifier-can-not-work

Comment: @Pier-LucGendreau I posted detail information on another question, would you have a look? Thank you so much! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20842833/segue-with-correct-identifier-can-not-work

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem here "**5. Control drag from table cell to a new view controller to create a push segue.**"

Try drag from your view controller (not your table cell) to new view controller and create push segue, then try with

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueIdentifier" sender:self];
}
```