# Create segue based on a downloaded config file

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, segue, ab-testing

To do advanced A/B testing, I want to be able to create segue based on a config file.

At launch, my app download a JSON file containing informations to create dynamically the parts of the main page.

For exemple, a JSON like following will create 2 buttons on the main view. The first one will be blue with the label "button1" and the second one will be red with the label "button2".

```
{
"elements":
    "0": {
        "type": "button",
        "label": "button1"
        "color": "blue"
    },
    "1": {
        "type": "button",
        "label": "button2"
        "color": "red"
    }
};
```

Now, I want to add in the JSON something like that : `"goto": "OptionViewController"` where the value of the goto key is the view displayed when clicking on the button.

I want to be able to add or remove buttons of the mainPage (I see how to do that) and to change the view linked to a button (this is my problem) remotely, simply by changing the downloaded JSON.

The problem is that for moving from a view to another, I don't only need the name of the new view, I need also the segue.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674685/creating-a-segue-programmatically) say that it's impossible to create segue programmatically.

The only solution I've found is for each view creating a segue to every other view but this very dirty.

Comment: Are you using storyboard?

Comment: Yes, I'm using a storyboard

Comment: Please help me understand further: can't you **create** the segue in storyboard and then **perform** the segue like this: `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showManufacturers" sender:self];`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Storyboard and if the view controller you want to segue to is defined in there, with an identifier of "OptionViewController", then you can do this:

```
UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@“Main” bundle:nil];
OptionViewController *ovc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@“OptionViewController”];

[self presentViewController:ovc
                   animated:YES 
                 completion:nil];
```