# What is a deprecated push segue? (iOS 8)

Tags: ios, xcode, segue

I have no idea what deprecated means in this context. I am new to programming and am making my first couple of apps in Xcode 6. Today I was making a to-do list app and when connecting to the scene where the user can input a new to-do item to add to main table, I was invited to use a push segue. It mentioned that it is deprecated which it doesn't seem to have been in Xcode 5 (which is the version tutorial uses).

Can anyone explain this to me? I know the push segue allows for backward navigation but that's about all I know!

Thanks a lot.

Comment: When you see the word “deprecated” in the documentation of a function, it means that it's a legacy function. It is still there for reasons of backward compatibility, but it will soon be removed. Do not use this function. Usually, the deprecation warning comes with instructions what to use instead.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The word 'deprecated' means the function is removed and will be no longer available in future ios versions from the point at which it was deprecated . If u continue to use this deprecated functions, then the apps may begin to crash at that function in respective ios versions.

'Push deprecated ' means the storyboard supports 'PUSH SEGUE' no more in ios8 in XCode6. Use 'SHOW' instead of 'PUSH'.

You can see the same issue here in this question:

[Adaptive segue in storyboard Xcode 6. Is push deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24184003/adaptive-segue-in-storyboard-xcode-6-is-push-deprecated)

Answer (score 3):

Deprecated means that the method you are using will not exist in future versions of iOS, so you are being warned that at some point it will be taken away.

[Deprecation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation)

If you build your app and continue to use this code, when Apple release an update you might find your app crashes.

It basically is telling you that the functionality you are using will work for now, but if you want it to work in the future you should not be using it.