# Push segue doesn't work on IOS 8.0

Tags: ios, sdk

I have a problem, I used "push" to pass from a view to another one, and now with the upgrade sdk 8.0, it's deprecated. So what should i use?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26307503/what-is-a-deprecated-push-segue-ios-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a Storyboard Segue you have to use Show (e.g. Push) segue.
This could be a possible duplicate: [Adaptive segue in storyboard Xcode 6. Is push deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24184003/adaptive-segue-in-storyboard-xcode-6-is-push-deprecated)

To make the new Show segue to acts like a Push segue, the controller has to be embedded in a navigation controller, otherwise, it acts simply like a modal segue. To embed your controller in a NavigationController, select the TableViewController from the storyboard, than select *Editor->Embed In->Navigation Controller* from the Xcode menu.

Comment: I tryed Show and it's ok, but Push is different.. Automatically it gives you also the "Back" button to return to the previous view

Comment: Even the Show segue does! Are you sure that your controller is inside a Navigation Controller?

Comment: I need to go from a TableViewController to another one..For example: select item,select subitem...

Comment: Yes. So, you have a TableViewController that is visualized when you open your application right? This TableViewController is embedded in a UINavigationController?

Comment: You have to embed it in because push segue are only available from a navigation controller. The new Show segue acts like a push segue if it come from a navigation controller, otherwise, it acts simply like a modal segue. 
To embed your controller in a NavigationController, select the TableViewController from the storyboard, than select `Editor->Embed In->Navigation Controller` from the Xcode menu.

Comment: oh many thanks! It was better the push action but now it works ;) thank you!

Comment: Your welcome. I have edited the answer so it is more clear. Please vote the answer up if it was useful for you.