# 'Show' segue in Xcode 6 presents the viewcontroller as a modal in iOS 7

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboardsegue

I have two view controllers in my iPhone application (built with swift) built with Xcode 6.1 and uses storyboards.

The first view controller is embedded in a navigation controller in the storyboard and the segue for the second view controller is a 'Show' segue.

When the application is run, it properly shows the transition as a push in iOS 8.x, but in iOS 7.x it appears as a modal without the navigation bar.

My application requirement is to show the transition as a push regardless of whether it's iOS 7 or iOS 8. Any ideas to get this working as push in both versions of the iOS?

I saw a related post where this issue is mentioned, but could not find a solution to the problem: [Adaptive segue in storyboard Xcode 6. Is push deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24184003/adaptive-segue-in-storyboard-xcode-6-is-push-deprecated)

Any help is appreciated...

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> This solution is different from the others in the following ways:

1. It includes a method to examine and verify the issue
2. The cause of the issue is traced to the source (a change in the segue type)
3. The solution is very simple (delete and recreate a new segue)
4. Please note the requirements in the text

I just gave a [very detailed SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24184003/adaptive-segue-in-storyboard-xcode-6-is-push-deprecated/33376713#33376713) that fully explains what is happening and why, but the simple solution is you can delete the Segue that is not pushing and then recreate it on the storyboard. The reason is that there is likely a broken bit of xml in the segue (see extended answer for example/instructions how to confirm this issue).

After you confirm that you have at least one UINavigationController within the view hierarchy, be sure that the segue is NOT a manual segue and does NOT have an action associated with it (by viewing the segue in the storyboard as Source Code). Delete the existing segue and then Ctrl-drag from a UIView/UIControl to the target view controller and if custom action is needed intercept the call to destination controller in **prepareForSegue**.

> Also to confirm that this solution works for you please do the
>   following:

- Verify that your initial view controller (with the arrow on it) is a
  UINavigationController and that it has a normal content view
  controller as it's root view controller. (or that you embed your
  initial view controller inside of a UINavigationController)
- Read my extended comments on an earlier response to a very similar question (linked above).

Comment: Wow this has existed for a long time and Apple still hasn't fixed it! Thank you for saving my bacon, was ripping my hair out over it..

Comment: Still useful in Xcode beta 9.2, hadn't seen this in 7 years of development. Deleting and recreating Navcontroller and segue did the trick.

Answer (score 12):

It's possible that you have assigned the Initial View Controller to your UIViewController instead of the UINavigationController. Also, select your UIViewController and check that the "Is Initial View Controller" option is unchecked.

[image: Set the UINavigationController as the Initial View Controller]

Comment: It's with the second view controller that I'm having an issue.The initial view controller is set correctly to the UINavigation controller 'before' the first view controller

Comment: I have just tried in a new project and works fine for both iOS7 and iOS8. Have you set the segue between the first and second view controller? can you give some more information?

Comment: Ah. The issue was almost the same. My two viewCs were in different storyboards and the second storyboard did not have a nav controller. Embedded the viewC in a navC and that fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24184003/adaptive-segue-in-storyboard-xcode-6-is-push-deprecated) is the workaround for that. It looks like a bug in Xcode for iOS 7. You need to create a dummy UINavigationController and link all your free UIViewControllers to this navigation controller. Worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

For me, my storyboard lacked a navigation controller.  I am creating the navigation controller programmatically, which works fine in iOS8, but not iOS7.

**SOLUTION**

1. In your storyboard, select the main view controller and in the Xcode menu, choose *Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller*.
2. Select the new navigation controller, and in the attributes inspector on the right, under *View Controller*, make sure *Is Initial View Controller* is checked.
3. Run the app.  Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 6):

I believe this is a bug in Xcode 7.2. In order to workaround, you can create a "Push (deprecated)" segue and then in the Storyboard editor, select the segue and change it to Show(e.g. Push)

Comment: I tried this in Xcode 7.2 but got an exception at launch: "Pushing a navigation controller is not supported"

Comment: Make sure you add the segue first to the targetVC. Then embed the targetVC in NavigationController.

Answer (score 3):

I have had this exact issue with "Show (eg. Push)" for ages and I have just figured it out whilst trying to push a view controller onto a navigation controller that is in a Popover. It seems that the context of the called View Controller is the problem. So this is how I resolved it:

1. On the View Controller performing the Segue, check the "Defines Context" property in the Storyboard.
2. In the called View Controller, set the Presentation property to "Current Context".

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem and the only solution I found that works for me is to use the deprecated 'Push' segue.

Comment: Using deprecated items is something that I generally want to avoid. I was able to get this working by embedding the first ViewC in my second story board in a NavC

Answer (score 2):

I am using XCode 9 with Swift 4. Note this version came out yesterday (September 20th).

For me this was just a caching bug. I had to choose "Present Modally", run the app and then choose "Show (e.g. Push)". Now everything works fine.

Comment: wow! Never would have guessed this! Sufferred due to this bug in Xcode 9.2 (9C40b). Thanks for posting this!

Answer (score 1):

Basically the answer of Jomafer is partly correct. The controller which you are pushing needs to be preceded by a UINavigationController. You dont really need to push the UINavigationController at all. As long the storyboard knows its within a UINavigationController, all is well.

Answer (score 1):

When a "Show" segue comes up as a modal segue in testing it is usually one of two problems:

1. The first view controller is not inside a navigation controller.
2. The storyboard XML is corrupted.

The solution to #2 is usually to remove and replace the segue, and it should correct itself. Sometimes just switching to some other presentation style, running, and switching back to "Show" fixes it.

This can also happen to "Show Detail" segues, and it can be more insidious.

Example:
I have a series of view controllers arranged in a UISplitViewController. They have segues Show->Show->Show->Show Detail. The last segue kept coming up modal. I tried everything to fix that last segue. The problem was that the *upstream* Show segue had been corrupted into a Show Detail segue (even though the storyboard still said it was a Show segue). I had been testing on iPhone, and I did not discover the real problem until I ran it on the iPad simulator. The segues were now Show->Show->*Show Detail*->Show Detail. On the iPhone the third segue looked just like a Show because it collapsed onto the navigation controller. However, it is still the *detail* view controller, and you cannot have a Show Detail *from* a detail view controller, so the OS does what it can to get your view controller on screen and displays it modally.

Lesson 1: Always test your UISplitViewController on iPad to make sure the segues are doing what you think.

Lesson 2: If your segue is coming up modal unexpectedly, check the *upstream* segues for corruption as well as the segue in question.

Answer (score 0):

Problem in my case was that I created Show (e.g. Push) segue **before** putting ViewController as rootViewController of UINavigationController. In other words I didn't have UINavigationController.
Then I deleted seque, **added UINavigationController and added seque again** and it worked. Tested on Xcode 9.0.1 / iOS 11.0.3.