# Embedded Navigation bar disappears on iOS 7 (small screen size) but not iOS 9 (larger screen) after performing segue

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, swift2

I have a show segue called `showPage` from a view controller to a table view controller and am calling `performSegueWithIdentifier()` to get it to show after clicking OK on a button in an alert:

```
@IBAction func enterManuallyTap(sender: AnyObject) {
    var code : String!
    if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Enter code", message: "Please enter code", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({ (input:UITextField) in
            input.placeholder = "your code"
        });
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: { (_) in
            barcode = alert.textFields!.first?.text
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showPage", sender: self)
        }))
        presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Enter code", message: "Please enter code", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel", otherButtonTitles: "OK")
        alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyle.PlainTextInput
        alert.show()
    }
}

func alertView(alertView: UIAlertView, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int) {
    if buttonIndex == 1 {
        var code : String!
        code = alertView.textFieldAtIndex(0)?.text
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showPage", sender: self)
    }
}
```

This all works perfectly on my iOS 9 device, but when I try it on an iOS 7 device, the navigation bar disappears, so I can't see the title or click 'back'. The table view therefore starts at the very top of the screen and runs into the status bar.

I have tried changing the top bar from `inferred` to `Translucent Navigation Bar` and set `nagivationBarHidden` to false

```
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
```

but it still doesn't appear on iOS 7.

I just tried `print(self.navigationController)` in `viewDidAppear()` for the tableviewcontroller, and on my iOS 7 device, it prints `nil`, but on my iOS 9 device, it shows the controller: `Optional(<UINavigationController: 0x12504e600>)`! Why does it not exist on the older device? I've seen that the navigation controller won't exist if you have a modal segue, but I'm doing a normal show segue, and I can't understand why it should work on one device but not the other.

Why does this happen, and why only on iOS 7 (or a smaller size device)?

Could this be because the iOS 9 device I'm using has a larger screen? (It's an iPhone 6S) but the iOS 7 device is an iPhone 4, which has a smaller screen. How do I go about debugging this to check whether it is a matter of screen size? However, none of the cells in the table view controller the segue goes to are cut off in any way on either device.

My storyboard (click for bigger image):

[image]

The problematic segue is the one between the 'Scan' view controller and the choose scan view controller.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your Storyboard?

Comment: @MihaiFratu sure, I've edited it into the question

Comment: It could also be related to my PageViewController, but still doesn't make sense why it works on one device :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is with your `showSegue` (`showPage`)

[From apple developer](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingSegues.html)

**Show (Push)**

> This segue displays the new content using the
>   showViewController:sender: method of the target view controller. For
>   most view controllers, this segue presents the new content modally
>   over the source view controller. Some view controllers specifically
>   override the method and use it to implement different behaviors. For
>   example, a navigation controller pushes the new view controller onto
>   its navigation stack.

Make sure your first `viewController` is embedded into a `UINavigationController` in `Storyboard`. Make the `navigationController` `initialViewController` if your first `viewController` is the `initialViewController`. Or else it could present the new `viewController` `modally`. That means no `navigationBar` on top of the new `viewController`. I think this is happening in your case.

You can also try delete and recreate a new segue. See this: 
['Show' segue in Xcode 6 presents the viewcontroller as a modal in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26649180/show-segue-in-xcode-6-presents-the-viewcontroller-as-a-modal-in-ios-7)

Comment: Thanks! But unfortunately the linked question's solution didn't work (my XML is already valid it seems, but I tried deleting and readding the segue but nothing happened anyway). However [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26665626/3541881) led to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27713843/3541881) and just adding an entirely new navigation controller from the problematic viewcontroller worked!!!

Comment: I'll be giving you the bounty anyway :) but do you have any idea why it works on newer devices without the extra navigation controller? Again, it would be great if you could edit in the link to that last answer so it serves as a compete reference in case someone else finds this question in the future! :)

Comment: Thanks @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ. May be in iOS 8 transition is inferred at runtime but on iOS 7 it is decided much earlier. In iOS 7 xcode loads `initialViewController`. It does not show 'NavigationBar' if it is not 'embedded` in a `navigationController` from `storyboard`. However I do not completely agree with that answer link. By embedded into a `navigationController` I wanted to mean adding a new `navigationController` (as you are doing). I agree with that part. But I'm also saying to make the new 'navigationController' the 'initialViewController' (a check box in xcode). I am unsure. Go ahead edit my answer.

Comment: This is how you embed: goto `storyBoard` select the `viewController`. Goto (menu) Editor >> Embed In >> Navigation Controller. I think this is the correct way.

Comment: Thanks, I did embed the second navigation controller that way, but I didn't try making that the initial view controller because I assumed that would break the entry point because it's not linked to my page view controller. I could try that though. And thanks for the explanation, that makes sense :)