# Destination Controller Showing without Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, uitableview

This is driving me crazy! I am creating a segue from one of the UITableViewCells to another UITableViewController. A Navigation controller sits between them as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

When I reach the Samples UITableViewController it appears without the NavigationBar as shown below:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you give us the code that launch the transition?

Comment: There is no code! It is all done by Storyboards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first UITableViewController is in a navigation controller too right ?
If not, it's normal, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24184003/adaptive-segue-in-storyboard-xcode-6-is-push-deprecated).
If your first UITableViewController is in a navigation controller, I had the same problem, if you use the push segue (deprecated) it should resolve your problem.

Comment: Thanks! You will not believe it! In the parent view controller there was some code hiding the Navigation bar! Opps!