# Can I use a single navigation controller to the multiple storyboards?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am using two storyboards Main and StoryboardA. For Main.storyboard i have embedded a navigation controller. From Main.storyboard i need to go the storyboard StoryboardA. So for acheiving this i have given a storyboard reference. But the problem is i am not getting the back button on the StoryboardA . It seems the StoryboardA is presenting itself instead of getting pushed. Please see the below image: So My question is do we need to use another navigation controller for StoryboardA?

Main Storyboard:
[image: First Storyboard]

Second Storyboard:
[image: Second Storyboard]

Comment: is navigation bar hidded on Main.storyboard ? if that's the case you have to expicitly set self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = false;

Comment: no its not hidden

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have found a solution mired in all of [these solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24184003/adaptive-segue-in-storyboard-xcode-6-is-push-deprecated) for old versions of iOS and Xcode. In short, **in your second storyboard, mark your first view controller as "Is Initial View Controller"**, not the navigation controller.

Your navigation controller will remain and still point to your first view controller. I wonder about downstream issues yet to appear but others seem to have had success.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added segue as push ? On control click - > Select segue type as Push .It should work fine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `RootViewController` for many StoryBoards but you can use only one Storyboard for a `NavigationController`