# How to find a deprecated push segue in Xcode 9

Tags: ios, xcode, segue, push

How can I find the source of the Xcode 9 warning:

```
"Push segues are deprecated since iOS 8.0"
```

I can't find any 'push' segues in the storyboard even if I search the source view.

If I select the warning it IB does not seem to highlight the offending segue either.

EDIT:

It seems this was an Xcode bug or something because eventually this warning cleared itself.  The two offending segues had been removed some commits earlier which is why I could not find them.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24184003/adaptive-segue-in-storyboard-xcode-6-is-push-deprecated