# connecting the segue, using the programatically created button

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I have created the button in the viewdidload method:

```
    UIButton * button2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(showVideo:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

In button action method i called the segue programatically:

```
    - (void) showVideo:(id)sender {
       [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"MySegue" sender: self];  
     }
```

In prepare for segue method the code to call the modal view controller

```
    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {
        if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"MySegue"])
          {
            Xen_VideoViewController *addController = [segue destinationViewController];
            [self presentViewController:addController animated:YES completion: nil];
          }
    }
```

i referred the link [link]:[Creating a segue programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674685/creating-a-segue-programmatically/17012857#17012857)

but i am getting the error as

"Application tried to present modally an active controller"

i need to show the modal view controller when the button pressed but the button was created programatically. the button was repeated in the scroll view.

Any other method to get the modal view controller?

Thanks in advance….

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not `present` the `addController` on your `prepareForSegue` method.

I refer to the link you yourself shared:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17012857/1939409

You should create the `seque` in your `xib` file and then when you call below line:

```
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"MySegue" sender: self];
```

the app will present the destination `ViewController` based on your xib-created `segue`. so this is not necessary to call `presentViewController` in the  `prepareForSegue` method.

If you already created the segue in your `xib` so just remove the `prepareForSegue` method and every thing should be OK.

Also if you even, do not want to create the segue in your xib. So I think the only way is presenting modal view controller.

Comment: Thanks Husein, Its working for me….
Thanks again for saving time for me….

Comment: how to pass the data for the modal view controller without using the prepare segue method is there any other way...

Comment: I personally use public properties is the modal viewController

Comment: Just search about "defining class properties" in google and see the samples