# creating push segue programatically and prepareforsegue method

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, uistoryboardsegue

i have a button that is created programmatic and i need to perform a segue on click that will send data with prepareForSegue, but this code wont trigger it.

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
UIViewController * vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AddToCalendarViewController"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

i have tried this:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"addToCalendar" sender:self];
```

but since the button is created grammatically i don't have any segue identifier to call, and using the following to create it did not work

```
UIStoryboardSegue * segue = [[UIStoryboardSegue alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"addtoCalendar" source:self destination:vc];
```

Comment: So is your problem that you aren't able to pass data or that you can't get it to segue to the next ViewController?

Comment: There are other ways to present a view controller besides a segue.

Comment: the segue works, but it wont trigger the prepareForSegue to send the data. I wanted to use segue because i wanted to keep the navigation bar from the previews controller, and that was the only away i know so far. (i started objective-c 1 month ago)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIStoryboardSegue` must not be created programmatically. Create a segue by connecting your view controller to the destination view controller in the storyboard and put its identifier to `@"addToCalendar"` (always in the storyboard). Then call it as you are already doing.

Comment: but i dont have the button created on the view. from where will a start the segue?

Comment: from the `UIViewController` that will perform it! That is how programmatically called segues must be created.

Comment: Segues can be created programmatically. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16710737/142358

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have an actual storyboard segue to call when the button is pressed, then you need to call [`addTarget:action:forControlEvents`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIControl/addTarget:action:forControlEvents:), where `action` is a selector to the method on `target` to be called.

Specifically, you first need to create a method to push the destination view controller, like so:

```
- (void)addToCalendar {
    DestinationiewController * vc = [[DestinationViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"destinationViewController" bundle:nil;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

and then in your *source* view controller's `viewDidLoad` (or wherever you're programmatically instantiating the button), you need to add

```
[self.button addTarget:self action:@selector(@"addToCalendar") forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

which will call the `addToCalendar` method you defined above.

Comment: can you exemplify? sorry but i did not get it.