# How do I create a segue that can be called from a button that is created programmatically?

Tags: swift, segue, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

In Swift I have a button created programmaticaly using:

```
var button = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Tableau", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "tabBarTableauClicked")
```

I want that when the user clicks the button it changes viewControllers.
Here is the code for `tabBarTableauClicked`:

```
func tabBarTableauClicked(){
    performSegueWithIdentifier("tableau", sender: self)
}
```

But it is obviously not working because there is no segue with an identifier called "tableau".

And I can't create a segue using Ctrl + click the button and drag to the second viewController because the button is created programatically and not in the Storyboard.

How can I create a segue with an identifier programmatically in Swift?

Comment: Segues can't be created outside of the storyboard.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674685/creating-a-segue-programmatically

Comment: Are your first and second view controllers in the storyboard?

Comment: Yes they are but the button is not

Comment: As long as you have both viewcontrollers **in storyboard** then you can create segues there and fire them programmatically. You don't need a button in the storyboard to fire a segue, having the viewcontroller which that button resides in is enough!

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Here is how to set up a segue so that it can be called programmatically.

- Control drag from the *ViewController* icon in the first view controller to the second view controller.
- Click on the *segue arrow* between the two view controllers, and in the *Attributes Inspector* on the right, give the segue an Identifier (*tableau* in your case).
- Then you can trigger the segue with [performSegueWithIdentifier](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621413-performsegue) in your code.

[image]

You can read more about setting up and using segues [here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingSegues.html)

Comment: I tried this, but I'm still getting the same "has no segue with identifier 'someIdentifier' " error...

Comment: @MarkLöwe, the OP wanted to trigger a segue from a button he created programmatically.  He was mistaken in thinking that the segue couldn't be wired up because the button does not exist in the Storyboard.  I showed him that the segue can be wired up as long as both VCs exist in the Storyboard, and then the programmatically created button can trigger that segue.  I solved what he wanted to do, if not exactly what his question asked.

Comment: @someguy you need to click the segue icon on the storyboard between your view controllers, and then in the menu on the right, give it an identifier

Comment: So *if* we had the button actually in the storyboard. Would there be any difference if the segue was made from the button or the viewController? I mean for both of them you would eventually have to do performSegueWithIdentifier which would suffice right?

Comment: @Honey, if the segue is wired from a button, you don't need to call `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)` because iOS will trigger the segue for you. If you want to trigger a segue programmatically, you should wire it from the viewController.

Comment: So you mean UIButton, has some form of a hidden mechanism that would just run something like `performSegueWithAllIdentifiers`? Interesting. Can you tell me where to look for more?

Comment: @Honey, it performs the segue that is connected to the button, and the button is sent as the `sender`.  Here is Apple's documentation.  https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingSegues.html