# How to set a segue programatically

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uicontainerview

I am developing an iOS application using swift, and I have used a`UIContainerView`. I have set a segue for`UIViewController` to be embedded in the `UIContainerView`.

Now, I need to change this `UIViewController`  on a`UIButton` click. Is that possible? If so how it can be achieved?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: please share some code

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674685/creating-a-segue-programmatically

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create a segue that can be called from a button that is created programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26456989/how-do-i-create-a-segue-that-can-be-called-from-a-button-that-is-created-program)

Comment: This was done from storyboard. I need to do it programatically

Answer (score 0):

You can create a segue programmatically with the [segueWithIdentifier:source:destination:performHandler:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStoryboardSegue_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIStoryboardSegue/segueWithIdentifier:source:destination:performHandler:) method. Your perform handler should do all of the work necessary to transition between the source and destination view controllers. Then you can initiate it programmatically using the `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` method of `UIViewController`

Comment: There is no method called segueWithIdentifier:source:destination:peformHandler

Comment: This method is declared in UIStoryboardSegue class. I gave a link to documentation.