# Swift - Impossible to use performSegueWithIdentifier

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, segue

I am struggling with this problem for a few hours now.
I have a view with a tableView and custom cell in it. What I am trying to do is to perform a segue which is in my viewController from the custom cell. The first thing I did was to create a variable called "parent" in my cell.swift with the type "viewController".

`weak var parent : ViewController!`

After that, I'm just trying to perform the segue like this :

`parent.performSegueWithIdentifier("eventDetails", sender: parent)`

And I have the following error : `Receiver (<Deevent.ViewController: 0x7fb99074f5d0>) has no segue with identifier 'eventDetails'`

So I tried something else... I created a button in my ViewController and connected a segue to the next view (everything from the storyboard file)

In my viewController.swift I created the following function

```
func viewEventDetails() {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("eventDetails", sender: self)
}
```

and this one in my cell.swift :

```
func viewEvent(sender: AnyObject) {
    parent.viewEventDetails()
}
```

So when I call it from the cell, it crashes with the same error than before but when I click on the button it's working. I even tried to click on the button programmatically `btnDetails.sendActionsForControlEvents(UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)` and I had the exact same error.

I've already tried to clean my project and delete it from the simulator. I'm really missing something here... hope somebody can help me.

Thanks !

Comment: If you want to trigger a segue with `performSegueWithIdentifier`, wire it up like this:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/26457259/1630618

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is already the way I did it (before creating the button)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to give your segue an Identifier.

A view controller can have multiple segues, and so you need to define which one you want to use. In your case, in your code you are using the Identifier  `"eventDetails"`.

Assuming you are using a Storyboard, you need to click on the segue arrow between the two view controllers, and in the Attributes Inspector on the right, set the Identifier value to `"eventDetails"`.

Comment: Hello, I didn't mention it, but of course my segue has the correct identifier in my storyboard.