# PrepareForSegue does not work for function that will jump to different view controller

Tags: swift, viewcontroller

So I have 2 VC's. In Sending VC I want to send data to Receive VC. I did this by PrepareForSegue in other projects, when making an UIButton. That worked perfect.
But now I have created a function, that will jump to that VC when a condition is met. The function is as follows:

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Resultsviewcontroller") as! Resultsviewcontroller
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
self.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

It will jump to the VC, but not with the data I have declared in my PrepareForSegue function. How can I send data with a function like PrepareForSegue?

Also, when jumped to the receiving VC, it has a white line at the top. It looks like the status bar should be there, but in both VC's, I set that to "none". How can I remove that white line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you're not presenting the controller using a segue anymore with the call of `presentViewController`, what you can do is ff your segue exists in the storyboard with a segue identifier between your two controllers, you can just call it programmatically using the `performSegueWithIdentifier` function.

In case of not exist you can set the segue manually and launch it using the function `performSegueWithIdentifier`. You can benefit from this answer
 [How do I create a segue that can be called from a button that is created programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26456989/how-do-i-create-a-segue-that-can-be-called-from-a-button-that-is-created-program)

I hope this help you.

Comment: Nice, you helped me out. This was the answer: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    [unowned self] in
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Test", sender: self)
} this actually solved my other problem also!!