# How can I indicate a view which has created with UIKit from a SKScene?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have a file of SKScene which is named "MainScene.swift", and created a button on it for users to jump to another page. The another page was created not by SpriteKit but with UIKit. How can I indicate the target page and write codes in this case?

I usually do like this when jump to the other scene, if I created both pages with SpriteKit.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let scene = MainScene(size: CGSize(width: 750, height: 1334))
    let skView = self.view as! SKView

    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFit
    skView.presentScene(scene)
}
```

And when I do the same thing on a scene which is created with UIKit, type a Storyboard ID on the Identity column, then code like this; I only know the way using storyboard.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func gotoNewPage(sender: AnyObject) {
        let nextVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("newPage")
    presentViewController(nextVC!, animated: false, completion: nil)    
    }
}
```

But when try same thing between the scene which is created SKScene and UIKit, I've no idea how to specify the latter from the former scene; I'm not sticking to use the storyboard. If there's any simple way, please let me know. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a job for the delegate pattern.
Add a protocol for LevelScene;

```
// LevelScene.swift
protocol LevelScene : class {
    var gameDelegate: GameDelegate? { get set }
}
```

Add a protocol for GameDelegate;

```
// GameDelegate.swift
protocol GameDelegate : class {
    func gameOver()
}
```

In your mainScene add the protocol reference and create a property called gameDelegate;

```
class MainScene: SKScene, LevelScene {
    weak var gameDelegate: GameDelegate?
}
```

In your GameViewController add the protocol reference and implement the required protocol function - in this case it's called gameOver and seque to your UIKit View as usual;

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController, GameDelegate {
    func gameOver() {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: ExitGameSegueKey, sender: self)
    }
}
```

Set the delegate to gameViewController when presenting the scene;

```
scene.gameDelegate = self
```

Then in mainScene call the delegate function when required;

```
self.gameDelegate?.gameOver()
```

Comment: To avoid strong reference cycles in your game, it's better to declare the type of the protocol as class (protocol GameScene: class { ), same thing for delegate :  weak var delegate: GameScene?

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice Mark! However, since I first come up with protocol & delegate, I'm having a difficulty understanding what you wrote. Let me ask several things. I know I'm asking very basic things, but please be patient.

1. Where should write "protocol GameScene {...}"? In MainScene.swift?
2. If I do so, I got following error: "Invalid redeclaration of 'GameScene'". Can I just change the name something else?
3. I also got an error: "Use of undeclared type 'GameDelegate"". 
 The error maybe clear if I create a property gameDelegate, as you say. How should I write that?

Comment: @vanagar I've updated the example to make it clearer and hopefully answered your questions. Apple's [Swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html) has a chapter on protocols that is worth reading. Though protocols and the delegate pattern might be an advanced topic, I think it would nicely solve your problem.

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano Thanks for the comment, I updated the example to include the weak reference.

Comment: @vanagar For the error `Invalid redeclaration of 'GameScene'` yes, just Rename the protocol to something else. Though ideally your class names should match the file name, so mainScene.swift would contain MainScene class.

Comment: @MarkBrownsword You're welcome, please add also ": class" to the protocols, actually they are always both strong references

Comment: Thank you, Alessandro and Mark. I still trying hard to understand your advices. I'm still having several errors, and I'm afraid that the naming of my files might confused you. I had two files when I post my question. One is "MainScene.swift" and the other is "GameScene.swift". As you know, GameScene.swift is the file when you create a project with SpriteKit. I'm using it as a part of my project, but not to do with this question. In this case, should I still write "protocol GameScene {...}" on GameScene.swift?

Comment: @vanagar You would need to give a new name to the `protocol GameScene {...}` and the file, so it doesn't conflict with the existing `GameScene.swift`

Comment: @MarkBrownsword The reason I've asked about GameScene.swift again was I wanted make it clear before I ask next question. Actually, I had renamed the new  
GameScene.swift as "GameScene2.swift" to avoid the confliction as you advised me before. But if I do so, I'll have another error (Type 'MainScene' does not conform to protocol 'GameScene2') on MainScene.swift when I typed as "class MainScene: SKScene, GameScene2 {...}". What should I do to avoid this error?

Comment: @vanagar Usually the error `Type 'MainScene' does not conform to protocol 'GameScene2'` would mean you haven't implemented the protocol members, so did you add `weak var gameDelegate: GameDelegate?` as a declaration to MainScene?

Comment: @vanagar I updated the example to use the name `LevelScene` instead, should be less confusing for others too.

Comment: @vanagar I think the problem was the `?` was missing from the protocol so in `LevelScene` see there is now a `?` after `GameDelegate`. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @MarkBrownsword Thank you! When I added `?`  after `GameDelegate` in `LevelScene.swift`, the error has gone.

Comment: @vanagar Awesome! A protocol is a contract that has to be implemented correctly. Please accept the answer, if it has solved your problem.

Comment: @MarkBrownsword Sorry, I'm still struggling to implement the next step. as for `func gameOver() {...}` how should I write? I just can replace `ExitGameSegueKey` with the storyboard ID(newPage) which I named? When I do so I got following error: `Value of type 'GameViewController' has no member 'performSegue'`. I've tried change the part as `self.performSeguewithIdentifier("newPage", sender: self)`, but just got similar error. Sorry, it's like I'm asking every details of each step.

Comment: @vanagar `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "newPage", sender: self)` should be the correct syntax to use, or you can try your original code.

Comment: @vanagar I just realised you probably don't have a seque defined. This [Stack Overflow Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26456989/how-do-i-create-a-segue-that-can-be-called-from-a-button-that-is-created-program) shows how to create a seque that can be called programmatically. Remember to give it an identifier like "newPageSeque".

Comment: @MarkBrownsword Thank you. I've created a segue by clicking and dragging with cntl key from Game View Controller to the View Controller. Then clicked & selected the segue arrow, and typed as `newPageSeque` on the (Storyboard Segue) Identifier column. Next, I came backed to 'GameViewController.swift` and modified `func gameOver()` as `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "newPage", sender: self)`, but the error won't change. I guess it because I didn't type `scene.gameDelegate = self` (or `self.gameDelegate?.gameOver()`) in the proper place.

Comment: @vanagar you'll need to use newPageSeque as the identifier so `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "newPageSeque", sender: self)`

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled by the error `Value of type 'GameViewController' has no member 'performSeque'`. If you type `self.p` do you see any functions related to seque?

Comment: I figured out the problem. I should have noticed it earlier. You had typed as `self.performSeguewithIdentifier`, but the 'w' of with should be upper case. When I modified the code as `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("newPageSeque", sender: self)`, the error had disappeared. (Somehow, when I changed it as `self.performSegue(WithIdentifier: "newPage", sender: self)`, I got the same error again.) Sorry for bothered you.

Comment: Glad to hear you've figured it out!

Comment: Let me ask you again. Seems I don't understand how to implement `scene.gameDelegate = self` and `self.gameDelegate?.gameOver()`. I've typed `scene.gameDelegate = self` at the next line of `let skView = self.view as! SKView`, and in the `MainScene.swift` I've replaced existing code on a button with `self.gameDelegate?.gameOver()`.

Comment: When I run and tapped the button, I got following error. `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<DelegatePractice.GameViewController: 0x7b844630>) has no segue with identifier 'newPageSegue''`
Sorry to keep nagging. I'm trying to understand, but it's bit difficult for me.

Comment: You'll need to add `newPageSeque` as the seque identifier on your storyboard.

Comment: It sounds like you have put `scene.gameDelegate = self` and `self.gameDelegate?.gameOver()` in the right place. Would be a good time to set breakpoints and step through the code to see how the delegate pattern works. Then check that you have correctly set the `newPageSeque` in the storyboard. As an alternate approach, you could use your original code with `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` to navigate, just put it in the `gameOver()` function. Though I think it's better to use the storyboard seque if you can.

Comment: I feel like @vanagar, I can't visually (yet) "see" how this works, and what is going on. It's something that could be drawn, visually, and explained that way, but I don't yet know how the relationships look, and where/what the pathways of communication and interaction are.

Comment: @Confused You can visualise it as child Node reaching up to parent Node and saying `execute this` with the constraint that the child only knows a little about the parent i.e. what is in the `protocol`