# Swift: returning to Main Menu after condition is met in GameScene using StoryBoards and UIViewControllers?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit, uistoryboard, skspritenode

## Context

This question is related to [Swift: SKSpriteKit, using Storyboards, UIViewController and UIButton to set in game parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41782820/swift-skspritekit-using-storyboards-uiviewcontroller-and-uibutton-to-set-in-g) and uses the same M.W.E. (link below).

Taking a look at the `Main.storyboard` we see the following:
[image]

While this storyboard would allow one to progress from left to right by clicking:

play -> (easy/hard) -> `GameScene`

`UIViewController` -> `MyUIViewController` -> `GameViewController`

and from right to left by clicking the `UIButton` on the last `UIViewController` with the `UILabel` stating "Score", there is not a way to get from `GameViewController` to the last `UIViewController` with the "Score" `UILabel`.

## Question

Given a certain event occurring during the `GameScene`, how can I pass some information (e.g. a score) from the `GameScene` and transition to the last last `UIViewController` so that the user can start the game over again. In addition to deleting everything in the `GameViewController` as to not just end up with unreachable old instances of the `GameScene`.

For the certain condition, let that be tapping the purple sprite in the M.W.E. For the information, let that be something trivial like the time until the sprite was pressed, or even just a random number.

## Minimum Working Example

[Stack Overflow SKSpriteKit](https://github.com/SumNeuron/StackOverflowSKSpriteKit)

## Note

My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41789989/5623899) - and implemented here[StackOverflow SKSpriteKit with Menu](https://github.com/SumNeuron/StackOverflow-SKSpriteKit-with-Menu) - shows that this is clearly possible, but by relegating everything to `SKView`s rather than using a `storyboard`. So if possible, please keep answers related to using this hybrid `storyboard`-`SKView` approach and how to have the `GameScene` call up the "Score"-`UIViewController`.

Comment: Are you familiar with the delegate pattern? It is the usual way for child views to communicate with a parent. This [SO Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39561177/how-can-i-indicate-a-view-which-has-created-with-uikit-from-a-skscene/39564948#39564948) shows the basic idea and performs the unwind seque. The delegate protocol could be extended to include a score property, so the scene can notify it's ViewController when the value changes.

Comment: @MarkBrownsword Nope. I am not, could you possible explain it with this M.W.E.: https://github.com/SumNeuron/StackOverflow-SKSpriteKit-with-Menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [userData](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/sknode/1483121-userdata) instance property of your next scene to store the current scene, something like:

```
nextScene.userData = NSMutableDictionary()
nextScene.userData?.setObject(actualScore, forKey: "actualScore" as NSCopying)
```

and when you are in the next scene you can ask to this NSMutableDictionary who is the previous scene as:

```
if let actualScore = self.userData?.value(forKey: "actualScore") {
    print("well done!, the score was: \(actualScore)")
}
```