# Why does segue perform even if condition is false? Swift, iOS

Tags: ios, swift

```
let condition = 99

@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    if condition == 1 {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "basicSegue", sender: self)
    } else {
        // Do nothing
    }
}
```

This is just the example of what's happening in my main firebase project. I'm really grateful for all replies.

Comment: Did you wire the segue from your button.  You should wire it from the viewController icon at the top of the VC. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26457259/1630618

Comment: this can only happen if the button is the source of the segue

Comment: Oh, thank's for help. The button was a source of the segue.

Comment: Alternatively, implement `override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool { return segue.identifier == "basicSegue" && condition == 1 }`