# how to move from one view to another

Tags: ios, objective-c

My doubt is how do i move from one view to another.

I have one storyboard in which i have two view controller (i have just created 2nd view controller by dragging and dropping it).
I want to move from one view to another using swipe . For this i have used swipe gesture and dragging its icon to our implementation file(viewController.m)Thereby creating a IBAction.

After that i am not sure what to do so that by 2nd view controller get loaded 
how to solve this problem and what to write in IBAction method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a segue programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674685/creating-a-segue-programmatically)

Comment: I upvoted both answers before. Depending on what you need to do, all 3 lines of code are valid. I'm guessing you are learning so I suggest you use segue as a general rule of thumb.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a `segue` from one view controller to another view controller.

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"identA" sender:self];
```

Here "`identA`" is the `segue` name which is given in storyboard when connecting one view controller to another view controller.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the fallowing line of code to navigate from one vc to second

```
- (IBAction)Goto_Next_View
{
    // If you wanted to present the next vc modally you can use,
    [self presentViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Your_SecondVC_Identifier_In_Storyboard"] animated:true completion:nil];
    // Or
    // If you need to push on to navigation controller stack,You can use fallowing one.
    [self pushViewController:[self.storyboard  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Your_SecondVC_Identifier_In_Storyboard"] animated:true completion:nil];
    **// Please use only anyone of the above two options.**
}
```

HTH!Enjoy Coding :)