# Add segue to dynamically created cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uicollectionview, segue

I am dynamically creating 9 cells that will fit into a `UICollectionView`. When tapped, each button will load a different view controller. As the cells are generated by data from an array, so I do not have the ability to set a `segue` with an `identifier` in Interface Builder.

I have been using this method:         `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)`, but I believe that it is not the most up-to-date way to transition to a different view controller.

*The Questions:*

- Should I create a segue for each dynamic cell programically, if so:
  how?
- Should I connect the one button in interface builder to a dummy view controller and switch out the destination view controller before the segue begins, if so: how would I switch out the destination view controller?

Interface Builder screenshot of setup:

[image: Interface Builder Setup]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set up segues in the Interface Builder but not from a button but from a view controller and set appropriate identifiers.
Use this method to start a segue:

```
- performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:
```

Comment: but if the buttons are dynamically generated (they do not appear in Interface Builder), how am I supposed to set up the segue in Interface Builder?

Comment: You can set up UIButton.Tag with a segue identifier. 
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:(sender as UIButton).Tag sender:self];

Comment: @JakeChasan: Segues cannot be setup outside of IB but can be triggered using `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` once setup in IB. If you cannot setup the segue in IB (not sure why you couldn't as a segue doesn't have to be set on a `UIButton`) then see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9675186/558933

Comment: @RoboticCat: the hard part for me to follow is what two objects do I link up in interface builder if all of the cells are dynamically added and each goes to a different view controller, and there is only one cell present in the interface builder?

Comment: Hold Ctrl and Drag&Drop from a ViewController rather than from a button.

Comment: @Yaroslav: and drag the mouse to what object? the dummy cell?

Comment: To the ViewController you want to have a segue to. http://i.imgur.com/eR65DfZ.png

Comment: @Yaroslav: but if each button in the collection view segues to a different view controller, and they are dynamically created, which view controllers would I want to connect, since I can only connect one view controller this way?

Comment: You connect your ViewController to every one of them. Give each segue a different identifier. Then specify which identifier to use in performSegueWithIdentifier:sender: in (for example) a UIButton's Tag property.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use segues for this scenario. I would give each of the different view controllers a storyboard ID and then load them that way. Then you can load the specific view controller by that ID and transition that way.

I am making some assumptions about your code so I can show an example. I am going to assume that each cell has a button in it and that is what is being pressed to trigger a segue. I will also assume that each of these cells' buttons have the initial view controller as the target, with a method declaration like the one in the code below.

```
func buttonPressed(cell: UICollectionViewCell) {
    let viewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("storyboardID") as! UIViewController
    self.navigationController!.showViewController(viewController, sender: self)
}
```

Comment: In this approach, how would one control the type of transition that is performed when this method is called?

Comment: I mean, lets say I wanted to show a "flip" segue instead of the standard "push" segue with the showViewController method. How would I specify the segue that is performed? (since the cells are dynamically created and thus there are no configurable options in Interface Builder?

Comment: You would use the different methods listed in the [UIViewController Presenting Content docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/)

Comment: So lets say I wanted to call the following method to configure the segue: performSegueWithIdentifier, what should I use as the "identifier"?

Comment: You wouldn't use `performSegueWithIdentifier` if you instantiate the view controller in code. Stick to the methods in the docs I linked in the last comment. Specifically, the methods in the `Presenting Content Over the View Controller` section.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into the methods in the link.