# Navigation Controller with Storyboard, iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two UIViewController's that are StoryBoards. Let's say they are `FirstVC` and `SecondVC`. From `FirstVC` I want to present `SecondVC` with the following code.

```
UIViewController *secondVC;
secondVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondVC"];
[self.firstVC presentViewController: secondVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Now in StoryBoard I have embedded `secondVC` in a NavigationController, however, when presented, `secondVC` is missing the NavigationBar.

`firstVC` and `secondVC` are not connected via StoryBoard as I want to present them with code.

Am I missing something or have I done this the wrong way?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674685/creating-a-segue-programmatically.

Comment: You need to assign an identifier to the UINavigationController scene and instantiate and present that scene. The storyboard process will automatically instantiate the embedded secondVC. You can also link the two scenes via a segue and still perform the segue through code using `performSegueWithIdentifier`

Comment: You have to give the navigation controller in stroyboard a storyboard identifier and create and present that, not secondVC.