# Swift Search Results segue to other View controller

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, uisearchresultscontroller

When I search in my searchbar, I want to click on a result and then go to another view controller. I found a similar queston on this site ([Swift Search Result Controller in search results segue to another view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35178691/swift-search-result-controller-in-search-results-segue-to-another-view-controlle)) but it didn't worked out for me. 
With my current code there is a working segue, but it is the table view segue (instead of the results segue).
Does someone know how I do this and explain it in an easy way?

Here's my tableviewcontroller code:

```
class elementstableviewcontroller: UITableViewController,
UISearchResultsUpdating{


var namen = ["Waterstof","Helium","Litium"]

var searchcontroller: UISearchController!
var resultsController: UISearchController!
var filterednamen = [String]()



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.searchcontroller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchcontroller.searchBar
    self.searchcontroller.searchResultsUpdater = self
    self.searchcontroller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    definesPresentationContext = true
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = false;
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false

}
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    self.filterednamen = self.namen.filter { (naam:String) -> Bool in
        if naam.lowercased().contains(self.searchcontroller.searchBar.text!.lowercased()) {
            return true
        }else{
            return false
        }
    }

    self.tableView.reloadData()

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if !searchcontroller.isActive || searchcontroller.searchBar.text == "" {
        return self.namen.count
    }else {
        return self.filterednamen.count
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

    cell.name.text = namen[indexPath.row]


    if !searchcontroller.isActive || searchcontroller.searchBar.text == "" {

        cell.name.text = self.namen[indexPath.row]


    }else{

        cell.name.text = self.filterednamen[indexPath.row]

    }
    return cell
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    myIndex2 = indexPath.row
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue2", sender: self)

    }



 }
```

and here's my second view controller code:

```
  import UIKit
  import GoogleMobileAds


 class Elementenuitgelegd: UIViewController, GADBannerViewDelegate{

@IBOutlet var banner: GADBannerView!
@IBOutlet var uitleg5: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var groep: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var periode: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var uitleg4: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var uitleg3: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var uitleg2: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var uitleg1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var titlelabel: UILabel!
var distance: Double = 0;
var speed: Double = 0;
var time: Double = 0;

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    titlelabel.text = namen[myIndex2]
    uitleg1.text = afkortingen[myIndex2]
    uitleg2.text = atoommassas[myIndex2]
    uitleg3.text = atoomnummers[myIndex2]
    uitleg4.text = electronenconfig[myIndex2]
    periode.text = periodes[myIndex2]
    groep.text = groepen[myIndex2]

    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true;
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true

    //banner
    let request = GADRequest()
    request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID]
    banner.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-8478021432040036/4295805958"
    banner.rootViewController = self
    banner.delegate = self
    banner.load(request)


    //keyboard weg deel 1
    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(startscreen.dismissKeyboard))

    //Uncomment the line below if you want the tap not not interfere and cancel other interactions.
    //tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

   //keyboardweg deel 2
func dismissKeyboard() {
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

}

Here's my customcell controller code:

```
 import UIKit

class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

   @IBOutlet var name: UILabel!

   override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

}

[First(tableview),second(searching for Neon and clicking on it), third(getting hydrogen("waterstof" in Dutch)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LlRv.jpg)

Comment: Please provide more Input Justin, do you need to pass any content/data to the other viewcontroller., what is not showing.?

Comment: okay, so when i click one of the results that are showing up in the results controller, the program takes me to another view controller. But, that viewcontroller doesn't correspond to my search results but correspond to the tableviewcells.

Comment: I'll add some pictures

Comment: @MithunR. - Do you understand it?

Comment: What "myIndex2 " has to do with.? How the new view-controller taking the data. Is it fetching data from the right Array.?

Comment: O, good point. That has to do with the second view controller. I will add the code above.

Comment: @MithunR - do you know what I mean?