# How to set the identifier of the segue to “sw_front”?

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard

I'm using SWReveal for creating slide out menu. I don't have Storyboard. I deleted it. I have to set identifier to segue like "sw_front" and "sw_rear". How can I do this without storyboard? Please, don't ask me why I deleted storyboard.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9675186/1219956

Comment: You can't create segue if you don't have storyboard. You can use SWRevealController using xib, please refer the sample app `https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController/tree/master/RevealControllerExample2`

Comment: This is (at least) the second problem you're encountering because you've chosen not to use storyboards. Start using storyboard. And learn autolayout ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have storyboard you can't set segue...!!