# How to make a custom segue when a UITableViewCell is selected without using storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I trying to create **custom segues** for some `prototype-cells` which *i* have created using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` function in xcode. I want to create custom segue from a prototype cell with `reusable identifier` **"home"** to a `view-controller` with `storyboard id "newViewController". i have already created the necessary view-controllers in the main-storyboard.

can someone tell me how to code the segue without using the `storyboard`!?

Comment: No You can not do that. Refer this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9675186/3077339 and Read first para for explanation.

Comment: Why not just do a `[self.navigationController pushViewController:newViewController]` in your `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: thanks guys.. got it done.. sry for the late response..!