# How to get rid of or change a storyboard created segue programatically

Tags: swift, storyboard, uistoryboardsegue

I have a segue from one view controller to another, which was created in the storyboard of my project. I'm wondering if there is a way to change or get rid of that segue through code. Thanks, using Xcode 9 Swift 4.

Comment: You can ignore a segue by implementing `override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        if identifier == "aSegueIWantToDisable" { return false }; return true
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it's not possible... look at the answer on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674685/creating-a-segue-programmatically). And the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistoryboardsegue) says this about creating segues:

"You do not create segue objects directly. Instead, the storyboard runtime creates them when it must perform a segue between two view controllers."

Although it's not about changing or deleting the segue, I think it's the same logic.

If you just want to avoid the segue to happen you can do that inside "shouldPerformSegue" (like vacawama said in the comments):

```
override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool { 
    if identifier == "aSegueIWantToDisable" { 
        return false 
    } 
    return true 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If it is not possible, is there a workaround?

Comment: Maybe there is! Could you explain a little more what you are trying to achieve so that I can think of a solution?

Comment: I added a workaround if you just want to avoid the segue to happen. I noticed that vacawama commented it earlier, so I used his code.